# ADPlus Dump Analysis. If PDB file is not present in production?

Tags: dump, adplus

I am analyzing one application which hangs randomly in production. I want to use ADPlus/DebugDiag to analyse by generating dumps. If I am generating dumps with the 'debug' mode application running, I am able to see the proper call stack with function name details mentioned but if I generate dumps with 'release' mode application, call stack is not resolved properly as PDB file is not associated with it in release mode.

I may not be allowed to copy PDB file in production enviornment. So is there any other way to resolve the call stack?

Please let me know if you need any more detais.

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the release pdbs then you should be able to set your sympath to that folder when loading the dump. The easiest way to do this would be to set the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable to the path of those pdbs. Then, when loading the dump, the debugger should be able to load them.